# What type does the r shiny's textAreaInput returns?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

So my shiny app is supposed to take some texts as an input and then give a one word text as an output. But apparently I get the error-"argument is not a character vector". These are my codes:

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)


server <- function(input, output) {
  text1 <- eventReactive(input$actionButton,{
    getPrediction(input$caption)
  })
  output$text1 <- renderUI({
    text1()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textAreaInput(inputId="caption", label="Put your text here", width="100%", height="400px", value="", placeholder = "Placeholder"),
      actionButton("actionButton", label = "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3("Name"),
      textOutput("text1")
      )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**helper.R**

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=detectCores()) 

getPrediction <- function(ptest){
  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(ptest))
  corpus.clean <- corpus %>%
    tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>% 
    tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
    tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
    tm_map(removeWords, stopwords(kind="en")) %>%
    tm_map(stripWhitespace)
  corpus.clean.test <- corpus.clean
  fivefreq <- findFreqTerms(dtm.train, 5)
  dtm.test.nb <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus.clean.test, control=list(dictionary = fivefreq))
  convert_count <- function(x) {
    y <- ifelse(x > 0, 1,0)
    y <- factor(y, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))
    y
  }
  testNB <- apply(dtm.test.nb, 2, convert_count)
  pred <- predict(classifier, newdata=testNB)
  pred
}
```

What can I do to print out the prediction as output?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: It returns a character string. As you can ascertain with print statements. Works fine I think, what do you think that is where the error is coming from?

Comment: I tried to run it but I don't see where you define `dtm.train`, it is dying there form me.

Comment: Oh right, I removed that. Now I am getting a new error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. At this point, I don't really know. I am also using shiny for the first time. This is the whole code: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=uq2FrPgE&version=2
Can you run it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: R-fiddle. How cool is that. Thought it was only for Javascript. Will have a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your server code.

- It helps to put a `req(input$caption)` statement in there to keep Shiny from running over data with uninitialized values
- You are rendering the text with `renderUI`. That is for dynamically creating input controls in the server that are then used in the UI portion.
- Instead of that use `renderText`.
- You could also consider using `renderPrint`. If you pair that with `verbatimPrintOutput` on the UI side you can see all the print statments in your UI which can help immensely with debugging.

Here is the changed code - using `verbatimPrintOutput` for debugging:

```
getPrediction <- function(ptest){
  print(sprintf("getPrediction - ptest:%s",ptest))
  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(ptest))
  corpus.clean <- corpus %>%
    tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>% 
    tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
    tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
    tm_map(removeWords, stopwords(kind="en")) %>%
    tm_map(stripWhitespace)
  corpus.clean.test <- corpus.clean
  dtm.test.nb <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus.clean.test)
  convert_count <- function(x) {
    y <- ifelse(x > 0, 1,0)
    y <- factor(y, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))
    y
  }
  testNB <- apply(dtm.test.nb, 2, convert_count)
  pred <- predict(classifier, newdata=as.matrix(testNB))
  pred
}

# app.R
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  text1 <- eventReactive(input$actionButton,{
    req(input$caption)
    getPrediction(input$caption)
  })
  output$text1 <- renderPrint({
    text1()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textAreaInput(inputId="caption", label="Put your text here", width="100%", height="400px", value="", placeholder = "Placeholder"),
      actionButton("actionButton", label = "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3("Name"),
      verbatimTextOutput("text1")
    )
  )
)
```

And the output:[image]

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!