# Store text input as variable in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to take a user's input and store it as a variable that will be used in a plotting function. My code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 mainPanel(
           plotlyOutput("plot", width = '100%'),
           br(),
           textAreaInput("list", "Input List", ""),
           actionButton("submit", "Submit", icon = icon("refresh"), style="float:right")
))
```

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
my_text <<- renderText({
    req(input$submit)
    return(isolate(input$list))
    my_text ->> subv
  })
bindEvent(my_text,
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
#my very long plot code goes here which takes subv as input. This part has been tested outside of shiny and I know works.  
}
```

I am trying to store the text in the `sub`v variable as it will dictate what the `renderPlotly` will generate. When I hit submit nothing happens and the variable is only created after the session ends. The newly created `subv` variable in my environment does not show the text that was inputted but lists `subv` as an empty function i.e. subv function(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can find a working prototype of what you would like to achieve with some information on what the issues were

First, we need to have a `textOutput` where our text will be shown. I understand this may not be necessary for the actual use case but it is important for this answer's demonstration purposes.

Next, we should not need to set variables to `global` via `<<-` or `->>`. This is generally not good practice. Instead, we should store our result in a `reactive`. See also `reactiveVals` (but this is harder to follow when the app gets complex).

Since we need to only get the value when we click submit, we should use an event bind to only run when we click `submit`. This is essentially similar to `eventReactive`.

Finally, we can use `bindCache` to cache our result on the input list.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot", width = '100%'),
    br(),
    textAreaInput("list", "Input List", ""),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit", icon = icon("refresh"), 
                 style="float:right"),
    textOutput("hello_out")
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_text <- reactive({
    input$list 
    
  }) %>% 
    shiny::bindCache(input$list
                     ) %>% 
    shiny::bindEvent(input$submit)
  output$hello_out  <- renderText({
    my_text()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This does work perfectly however I am now running into a different problem. My plot generates a network map from a list of input nodes by the user. When I try to map a single value the map is displayed without a problem but when I try to input a list of nodes I get an error saying undefined columns are selected.
In R studio I would normally pass the list as a vector: my_text <- c("node1", "node2", "node3") but I am not sure how to pass this using textAreaInput

Comment: I am not sure how `textAreaInput` works as I rarely use it. It seems it returns a string and not a vector based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177268/what-type-does-the-r-shinys-textareainput-returns. You can maybe just convert it to a vector in the reactive part. Sorry, I'm not close to my computer now so can't update with an actual way.